# WiFi drops in iPod after a while running my application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, wifi

I have wifi issues in with my application and the iPod I use for development. Other users have reported the same problems with my app.

The app keeps an open connection using sockets, and I show the connection status on top. Also the application reconnects when is disconnected.

The wifi signal of my iPod drops every 1 minute, and eventually, it drops until: I plug a power-source to the iPod or I exit the application.

It's really and issue that is driving me crazy :-P

The iPod iOS version is 5.0.1

Do you know what can I do to fix this problem? Did anybody else have the same connection problems?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added log: http://pastebin.com/hYVs5Vat

Edit2: Seems that I have two different problems, 
1- the wifi dropping and coming every minute. 
2- the application disconnecting completely the wifi. [SOLVED]

The 1st one looks to be an iPod vs router problem, not applications fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the

> Application uses WiFi

boolean to YES in the plist. If you don't then it turns off the WiFi after some time to save battery.

Comment: Well, seems that I have two different problems, one is the wifi dropping and coming every minute and the other the application disconnecting completely the wifi. Your answer worked for the second. Thanks!