# my iPad app kills wifi until minimized

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, nsurlconnection

We have an iPad app that is designed to download data that the user may read when no longer connected to wifi.  When it does download, it fetches thousands of PDFs. Occasionally while testing the fetching I experience the following behaviour:

1. Start downloading the PDFs
2. At some point the wifi connection drops even though the router is still up and running and others continue to use it (I'm 12' from the router).  The `NSURLConnection` calls its `didFailWithError` with either `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` or `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost` as its error and the wifi indicator in the top left disappears.
3. As soon as I minimize the app (whether immediately or an hour later) the wifi indicator reappears.
4. Restore the app, start downloading again - no problems.

Is there some iOS feature that prevents too much downloading?  Is there some method I can call to prevent this from happening?

This issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121526/wifi-drops-in-ipod-after-a-while-running-my-application) deals with a similar issue and points to the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` flag (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12).  The problem is that the app is intentionally designed to not require persistent wifi.

A couple of other tidbits:

- Running iOS 5.1 on an iPad2.  (Don't know if it is happening on other
  versions.)
- I cannot modify the app to download one big zip with all
  PDFs; it is a product requirement and just makes sense.
- The `NSURLConnections` are spawned from a background thread
  with 5 active connections simultaneously.

Comment: I also work with a Wi-Fi iOS app. Going crazy with losing Wi-Fi connection, although our app does explicitly require persistent Wi-Fi (unlike your case). I'm beginning to suspect iOS 5.1. See e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3790965?start=0&tstart=0. I'll try to test with an older iOS version. If you have the chance, I'd recommend you also try another version before you go crazy debugging a problem that's not your code. I'll post our results if I manage to test with older versions.

Comment: Tested our app with an iPhone 4 running 5.0.1 and a 4S running 5.1. Our app keeps a TCP socket in background mode. The 5.0.1 phone behave more consistently, displaying the messages from the server as soon as received almost all the time (a few cases it didn't). The 5.1 phone was hit-and-miss. About a third of the time it didn't display the server message until I hit the power button. They are sitting side by side, connected to the same router, running the same version of the app. Not a scientific experiment, but looks to me iOS 5.1 isn't as good with wi-fi connections.

Comment: @chr, thanks for investigating this further.  It helps me narrow down my continuing search.

Comment: after a few more tests, I'm not so sure it's iOS 5.1 anymore. In our cases it looks like the network we are using is overwhelmed. You may want to still test in 5.0.1 and on a different network (a different router/access point) before checking your code. In our tests the router/access point being used was also a factor on the stability of the connection (or lack thereof). Sorry for not being more helpful. The Wi-Fi stability keep me awake at night some times too...

Comment: @chr We ran diagnostics on our network to make sure it wasn't being overloaded as well, and our app is only pulling about 5 paragraphs of text every hour or so. Even with just a few kilobytes of data being transmitted, the iPad was losing connectivity until the app was minimized and reopened. Even with no other users connected, we had the same problem. Your network may well be causing an issue, but 5.1 definitely has its faults where wi-fi is concerned.

Comment: @RobertGowland Take a look at my new edit. It will be a few days before I can fully test it, but maybe you have time to see if it fixes your issue before then.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that iOS 5.1 is having issues with maintaining a wifi connection. There are a lot of forum posts about it around the world wide interweb, but here's my evidence:

We have 6 iPad 2's set up in a museum gallery. 3 are running 5.1 and 3 are running 5.0.1. The 3 iPads running 5.1 are constantly disconnecting from the access point. The 3 running 5.0.1 have no issues and haven't had issues for weeks. They are running the same app, off the same network with nothing else installed and identical settings applied. I'm reverting back and submitting a notice to Apple about it. I'll be reverting all iPads to 5.0.1.

Side Note: I am an IT professional and together with our System Admin we ruled out all issues with our internal network, access points, and connectivity over a slew of devices. Only devices running 5.1 (iPhones and iPads alike) are having issues.

**EDIT:** Downgrading is no longer possible. Once on 5.1, stuck on 5.1. I did find a reference to someone having this problem as well and solving it by adding a row to the app's plist. Under supporting files, go to your app's plist file and add the following row: `Application uses Wi-Fi YES`. Apparently the iPad has been designed to turn off the Wi-Fi adapter after 30 minutes of user inactivity (I have tested and confirmed this to be accurate). Inactivity being physical inactivity, not data inactivity. Supposedly adding this line overrides that if the app is open. I have yet to test this, but will as soon as I have the extended period of time to try it out. 5.0.1 (and perhaps a few earlier versions) may have "broken" this battery saving feature. And, in turn, 5.1 may have "fixed" the problem of Wi-Fi not turning off to save battery. I see it as a break because of my app, but who knows.

Comment: that's awesome.  I'll try to get that scheduled to be tested here.